# How to enable the touch interaction with QtWebEngine

Tags: qt, touch, chromium, qtwebengine

I used chromium(Recently use the qtwebengine) and it handle the touch events(Like most mobile browser work)

So I used a QtWebEngineView to integrate my web page using Qt 5.4, but I want to integrate the touch interaction(finger swipe to scroll the whole page)to make it works in my touch screen.

So how can I enable the touch interaction to scroll a page using QtWebEngine?

Regards,